# System.out.print("Calculator ") doesn't show an output when it is followed with a Scanner or BufferReader which takes a System.in in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, system.out, system.in

So I want to make a command line calculator that takes several arguments after the word "Calculator ". But with the following codes I cannot achieve it. In both of those methods the gradle waits to read the line before displaying the word "Calculator ".

*Using Scanner*

```
System.out.print("Calculator ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputString;
inputString = sc.nextLine();
String[] args = inputString.split( "\\s+" );
```

*Using BufferReader*

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Calculator ");
String str= br.readLine();
String[] args = str.split( "\\s+" );
```

However the System.out.println("Calculator ") displays the word without any problem. But it's not in line. So it doesn't work as I want. Changing the order of the code lines also didnot help.

System.Console().printf() is also not an option as I am using Intellij IDEA. So can someone please help me with this so that I could get an inline input reader. I also tried to synchronize the printing method by implementing it separately in a method. That didn't work as well.

Finally what I want to achieve is the following format

**Calculator** *max 12 23 25 45*

- Here the italicized is the input to be read.
- Bold part should be printed by the program.

This is the complete code
[image]

before entering input the console ..

[image]

after entering the input

[image]

**Latest Update**

So I tried to do the same with a Maven project. *Both of the above methods worked perfectly when I did with a maven project in Intellij.*

Therefore it must be something to do with gradle's way of running the project. I want to know whether there is a chance for that to happen ?

Comment: Call `System.out.flush()` before you start processing the input after you have done any output.

Comment: Change `print()` to `println()`.

Comment: Yes, println works. But I want to get the input in the same line as "Calculator " has printed . Println doesn't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the output by modifying gradle setting as:
File --> Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Gradle. There is a dropdown Build and Run using: which has options of Gradle and IntelliJ IDEA. Grade was default. I picked IntelliJ IDEA and my System.outs became alive again.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004966559-System-out-print-TEST-don-t-display-on-the-console-in-IntelliJ) when using IntelliJ IDEA gradle plugin that received so little attention that IntelliJ team seems not so motivated to solve this.

The only workaround I could figure out is to skip the gradle plugin and call gradle wrapper directly from IntelliJ IDEA. To do this you can either use my IntelliJ IDEA plugin [*Gradle Run with Arguments*](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13751-gradle-run-with-arguments) ([GitHub Link](https://github.com/b1f6c1c4/gradle-run-with-arguments)), or manually create a run configuration that invokes gradle wrapper whenever you want to run your program. I'd suggest you try my plugin first and see if it helps.

To manually create a run configuration that invokes gradle wrapper, the easiest way is through a `JAR Configuration` in IntelliJ IDEA. To make this possible you also need to patch the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`'s `MANIFEST` and append a `Main-Class` entry. In this way you can launch gradle wrapper from IntelliJ IDEA and enjoy `System.out.print(...)`.

*Limitation*: This approach won't allow you to use the built-in debugger feature because IntelliJ IDEA tries to debug gradle wrapper itself instead of your actual program.

Comment: Yes, I put it in the Gradle community as well. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -2):

Call `System.out.flush()` before you start processing the input after you have done any output. The IDE is connecting to the processes with a pipe and that is not automatically flushed into on every output.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't seem to work. 
```System.out.print("Calculator ");
  System.out.flush();
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  String inputString;
   inputString = sc.next();
```
This is what I did

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `sc.nextLine()` you should use `sc.next()`.

Comment: But the problem is not that, _Calculator_ word is still not displayed before it waits for the user to enter arguments on the console

Comment: I am actually testing the above part only in a main method. I am buidling using gradle.

Comment: I added my entire code and the outputs in the question.